# Angular.js $scope.on() not catching first broadcast when page loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason... when the page first loads `$scope.$on('$cpuResult', cpuUpdate);` doesn't catch the first broadcast. I verified that the first broadcast is going out successfully with `console.log("broadcast");`. The first broadcast is important to initialize the data, how come `$scope.$on('$cpuResult', cpuUpdate);` is not catching the first broadcast and how can I fix this?

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.controller('cpuCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.avaiable = "";
    $scope.apiTimeStamp = "";
    $scope.infoReceived = "";
    $scope.last15 = "";
    $scope.last5 = "";
    $scope.lastMinute = "";

    var cpuUpdate = function (e, result) {
        console.log("yay");
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.available = result.cpuResult.avaiable;
            $scope.apiTimeStamp = result.cpuResult.timestamp;
            $scope.infoReceived = new Date();
            $scope.last15 = result.cpuResult.metrics['15m'].data
            $scope.last5 = result.cpuResult.metrics['5m'].data
            $scope.lastMinute = result.cpuResult.metrics['1m'].data
        });
    }
    $scope.$on('$cpuResult', cpuUpdate);
});
```

---

```
angular.module('monitorApp')
.run(function ($rootScope) {
    var source = new EventSource('/subscribe');

    source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        var result = JSON.parse(e.data);
         event = Object.keys(result)[0];
         switch(event) {
             case "cpuResult":
                 console.log("broadcast");
                 $rootScope.$broadcast('$cpuResult', result);
             break;
         }
    });
});
```

---

```
<script src="scripts/angularApp.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/sse_listen.js"></script>
```

Comment: The controller isn't yet created by the time your first event is getting pushed out. You can refactor your app.run into a factory which exposed the data, and watch the data from your controller. I realize this is ironic because I initially recommended you change your factory to an app.run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The controller isn't yet created by the time your first event is getting pushed out. You can refactor the app run into a factory that exposes the result data, and then watch the data from your controller:

```
angular.module('monitorApp').
factory('sseHandler', function ($timeout) {
    var sseHandler = {};
    sseHandler.result = {};
    var source = new EventSource('/subscribe');
    source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
        var result = JSON.parse(e.data);
         event = Object.keys(result)[0];
         switch(event) {
             case "cpuResult":
                 console.log('sseHandler result change');
                 //The controller will watch the result
                 //on this object
                 $timeout(function(){
                     sseHandler.result = result;
                 });
                 //I wrap the result change in a timeout
                 //to schedule an apply,
                 //which will trigger your watches to run
                 //their dirty checks.
             break;
         }
    });
    return sseHandler; //return the object with exposed result
}).
controller('cpuCtrl', function($scope, sseHandler) {
    $scope.avaiable = "";
    $scope.apiTimeStamp = "";
    $scope.infoReceived = "";
    $scope.last15 = "";
    $scope.last5 = "";
    $scope.lastMinute = "";

    var cpuUpdate = function (result) {
        console.log("yay");
        // You don't need the apply here anymore.
        $scope.available = result.cpuResult.avaiable;
        $scope.apiTimeStamp = result.cpuResult.timestamp;
        $scope.infoReceived = new Date();
        $scope.last15 = result.cpuResult.metrics['15m'].data;
        $scope.last5 = result.cpuResult.metrics['5m'].data;
        $scope.lastMinute = result.cpuResult.metrics['1m'].data;
    }
    // The second argument of the watch gets called when
    // the result of the first argument changes
    // I'm assuming timestamp changes often enough
    $scope.$watch(function(){ 
        return sseHandler.result.timestamp; 
    }, function(){
        cpuUpdate(sseHandler.result);
    });

});
```

Comment: Curious...why couldn't I keep .run() and  do `$timeout(function(){$rootScope.$broadcast('$cpuResult', result); }, 1000);`? I tried keeping .run() and this way and didn't work, of course.

Comment: Do you mean $timeout(function(){$rootScope.$broadcast('$cpuResult', result);}, 1000); ? That seems like it would probably work to me as long as your page isn't too complicated, but I think using the $watch is more idiomatic.

Comment: You can put a log message in your controller initialization and a log message in your broadcast to verify the controller is made before the first event is sent out.

Comment: How come I couldn't inject my service as `.controller('cpuCtrl',  ['sseHandler', function($scope) {}]);`?

Comment: It should look like .controller('cpuCtrl', ['$scope', 'sseHandler', function($scope, sseHandler) {}]);

Comment: Strange...`sseHandler.result` doesn't seem to be in the controller's environment. for `cpuUpdate(sseHandler.result);` I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cpuResult' of undefined`. I did a console.log on `sseHandler.result` and it showed as a empty object in $watch. I did verify `sseHandler.result` is good in the service when it returns it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56467/discussion-between-dustyrockpyle-and-dman).